Google chrome load file instead open page after first click
I have some problem with google chrome.
After searching, a list of sites is displayed on the google.com page. When i try to open some of them, a file is downloaded without an extension and always with the same content. This only happens the first time; when i click again on same link, the site opens correctly. I disabled almost all extensions, cleared the cache and cookies, scanned the computer for viruses by booting from a flash drive, but the problem still persisted.
This file content in hex "00000807000000000000000000000000
01"
Google chrome in download history show me source - google.com. Cant'f find solution for this problem. Perhaps, someone can hepl me here?
